# При смене отображение с телефона на планшет, то интерфейс спалзает. Что делать?

Tags: android

Читал на этом же форуме про данную проблему, но ничего не понял. Было написано, что для каждой плотности пикселей есть свои каталоги, но где они, что в них писать? У меня весь интерфейс в activity_main записан. Как отдельно редактировать интерфейс под планшеты и телефоны?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Поясняю что в телефоне, планшете уже давно не считаются экраны пикселями. Называется это DPI - точки на дюйм. Так вот у телефонов этот DPI уже настолько велик, что считать отдельный пиксель бессмысленно. Так вот на Aндроид Developer есть отличная статья как правильно считать размеры экрана - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes советую почитать, тогда и суть станет более чем ясна.

**== Дополнено ==**

> Как отдельно редактировать интерфейс под планшеты и телефоны?

В Layout можно сделать для каждого разрешения в стандарте `hdpi`, `mdpi`, `xhdpi`, и.т.д. отдельный Layout файл под необходимое разрешение. Посмотри на примере `mipmap/ic_launcher` как это делается.

Comment: как указать где hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, и.т.д. ? И как сделать, чтобы они относились к одному файлу с кодом?